# HTML can't recognize Font-Awesome

Tags: html, css

I have a problem My web app can't recognize the icons that I put with font-awesome, I dont know why. I have in my index.html in the header this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="\~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css"/>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="\~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css"/>`

Also have in my index.html:

`<script src="\~/lib/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="\~/lib/font-awesome/js/fontawesome.min.js"></script>`

In the component where I call the icon I have:

```
<div class="row g-3 ">

    <div class="col-auto"><i class="fa-solind fa-circle-user"></i></div>

</div>
```

Is someone knows, why it does not work? I've tried everything and it doesn't work

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Why did you put *that* code in your header? What instructions are you following? The `~` implies you are using .NET, but you don't mention anything about .NET in your question. The ```\``` implies that you are preprocessing the HTML with something before it gets put in a .NET template, but you don't mention anything about that. What have you done to debug this? Have you checked the Network panel of the developer tools in your browser and make sure the URLs resolve to where you expect *and* get `200 OK` responses *and* contain the data you expect in the response bodies?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you're using and if you are only allowed to use free icons.
The icons you use `fa-solind` and `fa-circle-user` cannot be found. Below an example with a free icon using version 5.15.4. Maybe it helps for you to find where you go wrong.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row g-3 ">
  <div class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div>
</div>
```